# Using LINQ in .Net 3.1 to get all items from a database table that matches a list of ID's

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core-3.1

I have a SQL database and a .Net core 3.1 project containing 3 tables called members, memberships and clubs.
Each member is unique with a unique MemberId and can be a part of several clubs.
For every club a member is a part of you have one row in the membership table that contains MemberId, ClubId and MembershipID.

Memberships:

```
 

    |Id|MemberId|ClubId|
    ********************
    |1 |1       |1     |
    |1 |1       |2     |
    |2 |2       |2     |
    |3 |3       |3     |
    |3 |3       |2     |
    |3 |3       |1     |
```

Clubs:

```
 

    |Id|Name       |Subject|
    ************************
    |1 |Chess club |Chess  |
    |2 |Foxtrot    |Dance  |
    |3 |Paint club |Art    |
```

Members:

```
    |Id|First Name |phone  |
    ************************
    |1 |Bob        |xxx    |
    |2 |Mandy      |yyy    |
    |3 |Joe        |zzz    |
```

I have a list containing all of the clubIds that needs to match.
Now using Linq I would like to get all members that are part of several clubs. So for instance i would like to get all members that are part of the chess club (Id: 1) AND the paint club (Id: 3), so with a list [1, 3]  in this case only Joe.

This is a pretty simplified pseudo-code version but I hope it helps demonstrate what I want to do.

```
  

    memberships.Where(membership => membership.clubId == 1 AND membership.clubId == 3)
```

This obviously doesn't work since no single row fulfills that plus i want it to be dynamic with a list of clubId's.

```
    var memberClubData = [1,3]
    memberships.Where(membership => memberClubData.All(x => x == membership.clubId))
```

I know how you can do it with SQL with a subquery and count but I'm completely stuck when it comes to doing it with LINQ in C#.

Comment: Normally you create a list  of items you want like List<int> findClubId = new List<int>() {1,3};  Then you can use findClubId.Contains(x) as part of your query.

Comment: @jdweng When I do that I get everyone who's a part of clubId 1 or 3 when i actually only want people who are a part of both clubs, aka Joe. 

Using contains i get both Joe and Bob instead of only Joe.

Answer (score 0):

var query= from Member in Members where
Memebers.Clubs.any(club=>club.Id==1 && club.Id==3)
select Member

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
           DataTable memberships = new DataTable();
            memberships.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            memberships.Columns.Add("MemberId", typeof(int));
            memberships.Columns.Add("ClubId", typeof(int));

            memberships.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,1,1});
            memberships.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,1,2});
            memberships.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2,2,2});
            memberships.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3,3,3});
            memberships.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3,3,2});
            memberships.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3,3,1});

            List<int> findClubId = new List<int>() {1,3};

            int[] memberClubData = memberships.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new { id = x.Field<int>("Id"), clubId = x.Field<int>("ClubId") })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.id)
                    .Where(x => findClubId.All(y => x.Select(z => z.clubId).Contains(y)))
                    .Select(x => x.First().id)
                    .ToArray();
```